# tornado get argument with special prefix

Tags: arguments, tornado

```
 Here is my code:

    class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):         
        def get(self):
            self.write(self.response.arguments)
    def main():
        settings = {"template_path": "html","static_path": "static","debug":True}
        tornado.options.parse_command_line()
        application = tornado.web.Application([ (r"/", MainHandler)],**settings)
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

```
so wget http://localhost/?#access_token=DWE232
I got nothing.
if wget http://localhost/?access_tokent=DWE232   and I can get the value 
How to solve the problem?
```

Comment: Please provide your url mapping and the handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use urllib to encode the query parameters

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({'#access_token': 'DWE232'})
'%23access_token=DWE232'

   So instead of 

   wget http://localhost/?#access_token=DWE232 

   use

   wget http://localhost:12123/?%23access_token=DWE232
```

Answer (score 0):

The '#' is a fragment identifier and will not be passed in a URL.

From - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
>   URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the web server. When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a web resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to
>   the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits
>   for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value.

Thus if you have code that requires a '#' to be passed to the server you need to encoding it with a urlencode() function (python, JavaScript, etc.) that will insure that it's passed safely.